# Film identification - SF - woman with special skill to sense into the past is being sent to identify the cause of a disappeared crew on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a science fiction film where a woman having a special sensing skill to "see" scenes from the past when being in the right place is being sent to a spaceship that has lost it's whole crew under mysterious conditions. The new crew with the special woman travels to the spaceship located somewhere in space, enters it and then this special woman starts to sense scenes happened in the past of this spaceship, until she progressively discovers that the crew was murdered by a crew member. Every time she senses the past she interacts somehow with the people of the lost crew (from the past), so that she is risking her life when doing this, but in the end she manages to identify the killer and somehow get rid of him (or something, I don't remember quite well).
I remember this film as a very good one.
Can somebody tell me it's name? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "[Warp Speed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134204/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)" from 1981:

> A ship is found adrift in space with no trace of its crew, or any
> signs of life at all. A psychic is brought into to try to "join" her
> mind with the memories lingering in the spacecraft so she can find out
> what happened to the crew and where they are now.

You can watch the trailer below.